# Skipping analyzing "feedparser.util": module is installed, but missing library stubs or py.typed marker

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, feedparser

How do I fix this error? It seems feedparser does not support mypy typings? I could not find a typeshed implementation for feedparser

**UPDATE 1**

I see an option called [ignore_missing_imports](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-ignore_missing_imports) that I can add to pyproject.toml. Isn't it a bad idea to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I see an option called ignore_missing_imports that I can add to pyproject.toml. Isn't it a bad idea to do this?

Yes, it usually is a bad idea to enable this on *all* modules. Consider using a more constrained approach:

You can ignore missing imports only for this specific package by adding a [`[tools.mypy.override]`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#using-a-pyproject-toml-file) section in `pyproject.toml`. This way you don't need enable the flag on everything.

```ini
[[tool.mypy.overrides]]
module = "feedparser.*"
ignore_missing_imports = true
```

The work for supporting typing in `feedparser` [has been merged to the develop branch](https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser/pull/282) and you should be able to remove this workaround when it is released.